# Node 6 Buffer constructor deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.0.0/

"Existing `Buffer()` and `SlowBuffer()` constructors have been deprecated"

I am currently using these to create synthetic cursor values for GraphQL, for example:

`new Buffer(<cursor>).toString('base64')`

Now that the `Buffer` constructor is deprecated, what would be the correct way to do something similar?

Thanks in advance anyone with ideas, I'll dig in on this as well later and post my answer here if I have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array).

See [Class Method: Buffer.from(array)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array)

Comment: Awesome. As in RTFM. Sorry for wasting your time, but I appreciate the quick response.